# [self.navigationController pushViewController:ngView animated:YES]; not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.6

If i use

```
 NGViewController *ngView = [[NGViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
[self presentViewController:ngView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

above code the controller will go to NGViewController page.

But if I use this navigation controller

```
NGViewController *ngView = [[NGViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ngView animated:YES];
```

the Controller will be in same page.

Can any one tell that what's the problem.

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController`?  If not, then `self.navigationController` will be `nil`.

Comment: yes i have not used UINavigationController so its not coming.... thanx 2 all

Comment: have you made your application `UINavigation` Based, if not then convert it to Navigation based app, then it will work

Comment: make sure you are pushing the View Controller in navigation stack. otherwise self.navigationController will return nil;

Answer (score 2):

You should use this  code

```
NGViewController *ngView = [[NGViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
[self presentViewController:ngView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

after writting this line when then you you want go on different page  with push view controller

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController       alloc]initWithRootViewController:ngView];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

I hope you will solve this issue by this code Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Your `self.navigationController` is probably `nil` - check it out through debugging. Your `self` view controller is not within a `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

Now i m using this code

```
 NGViewController *ngView = [[NGViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.50];
 [self presentViewController:ngView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

so that it wil give same effect other

Comment: I hope you are ending the animations later...(P.S. this way of animating is really old [pre iOS 4])

Answer (score 1):

Self Controller should have navigation controller (in Storyboard) in order to navigate.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` is a `controller of controllers` and it is designed to allow you to `push and pop controllers` and manage a hierarchy of your view's. And your `navigationController` property tells you whether your `NGViewController` is currently in a `UINavigationController's` hierarchy; if not (as in this case), the `navigationController` property returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own navigation controller and then try to push the view controllers and thus build up a view hierarchy. 
I normally would suggest this:

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController       alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstviewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
navigationController.delegate = self;
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to declare this in your first controller

```
NGViewController *ngView = [[NGViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ngView animated:YES];
```